# JBoss equivalent for Weblogic APP-INF/classes

Tags: jboss, weblogic, java-ee-8

In Weblogic, inside an EAR, you can put classes under `APP-INF/classes` folder. These classes are shared across all EAR modules (WAR's, EJB's, JAR's).

Does JBoss allow any similar path?

We do **not** want to package these classes under a JAR.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround with the JAR "upacked" libraries. I put all my classes under a folder `lib/myFakeJAR.jar/`, where `lib` is the libraries folder of my EAR.